# Derivative of quadratic matrix product (not vector $d (xAx^T) = x (A + A^T))$, $A$ is not symmetric

Tags: calculus, matrices, quadratic-forms

I am trying to differentiate the matrix product of the quadratic form, $M=XUX^T$, with respect to the matrix, $X$.  That is, I want $\frac{\partial M}{\partial X}$.  Working from a concrete example with matrices, $M,X,U \in \mathbb{R}^{4,4}$, and a particular element, $x_{3,1}$, my plan was to find the general form of the derivative of an element which would lead to the matrix form.  A single element in $X$ appears 8x in the computation of the product, $M$; 4 on the left, and 4 on the right.  My plan was to compute the left and right derivatives then add them.  Examining a single computation (transpose accounted for in the subscripts, 1-indexing),

$$ m_{3,2}  = \\
   (x_{3, 1}\cdot u_{1, 1} + x_{3, 2}\cdot u_{2, 1} + x_{3, 3}\cdot u_{3, 1} + x_{3, 4}\cdot u_{4, 1}) \cdot x_{2,1} \\
+   (x_{3, 1}\cdot u_{1, 2} + x_{3, 2}\cdot u_{2, 2} + x_{3, 3}\cdot u_{3, 2} + x_{3, 4}\cdot u_{4, 2}) \cdot x_{2,2}  \\
+ (x_{3, 1}\cdot u_{1, 3} + x_{3, 2}\cdot u_{2, 3} + x_{3, 3}\cdot u_{3, 3} + x_{3, 4}\cdot u_{4, 3}) \cdot x_{2,3}  \\
+   (x_{3, 1}\cdot u_{1, 4} + x_{3, 2}\cdot u_{2, 4} + x_{3, 3}\cdot u_{3, 4} + x_{3, 4}\cdot u_{4, 4}) \cdot x_{2,4} 
$$

then $$ \frac {\partial m_{3,2} } {\partial x_{3,1}} = u_{1, 1} \cdot x_{2,1}  
+ u_{1, 2} \cdot x_{2,2}   
+ u_{1, 3}  \cdot x_{2,3}  
+ u_{1, 4}  \cdot x_{2,4}  
 = u_{1, :} \cdot x_{2,:}^T
$$

Each entry in $X$ will be used 4 times on the left side, so differentiating the left side in all 4 places that it appears gives (the transposes cancelling out),

$$\frac {\partial m_{3,:}}{\partial x_{3,1}} = u_{1,:}\cdot X$$
$x_{3,1}$ will also appear 4 times on the right side (accounting for the transpose):
$$m_{i,3} = \\
(x_{i, 1}\cdot u_{1, 1} + x_{i, 2}\cdot u_{2, 1} + x_{i, 3}\cdot u_{3, 1} + x_{i, 4}\cdot u_{4, 1}) \cdot x_{3,1} \\
+  (x_{i, 1}\cdot u_{1, 2} + x_{i, 2}\cdot u_{2, 2} + x_{i, 3}\cdot u_{3, 2} + x_{i, 4}\cdot u_{4, 2}) \cdot x_{3,2}  \\
+   (x_{i, 1}\cdot u_{1, 3} + x_{i, 2}\cdot u_{2, 3} + x_{i, 3}\cdot u_{3, 3} + x_{i, 4}\cdot u_{4, 3}) \cdot x_{3,3}  \\
+   (x_{i, 1}\cdot u_{1, 4} + x_{i, 2}\cdot u_{2, 4} + x_{i, 3}\cdot u_{3, 4} + x_{i, 4}\cdot u_{4, 4}) \cdot x_{3,4} 
$$
suggesting that the right's derivative is,

$$\frac{\partial m_{:,3}}{x_{3,1}} = X \cdot u_{:,1}$$

So the  derivative for entry $x_{3,1}$ is $$\frac {\partial M}{\partial x_{3,1}} = u_{1,:} \cdot X +  X \cdot u_{:,1}$$,
or, more generally, any element, $x_{i,j}$ is $$\frac {\partial M}{\partial x_{i,j}} = u_{j,:} \cdot X +  X \cdot u_{:,j}$$

This led me to conclude that the desired derivative is, $$\frac {\partial M}{\partial X} = U \cdot X +  X \cdot U^T$$

Verification with numerical auto-differentiators produce very different results.  What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by $\partial M/\partial X$? Like this is technically a smooth map $\mathbb R^{n^2}\rightarrow \mathbb R^{n^2}$, so do you want to calculate the Jacobian of this?

Comment: Yes, I am interested in computing the smooth map, so the Jacobian can be summarized to a per $x_{i,j}$ matrix gradient, that is, $\frac{\partial M}{\partial X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is the per element total gradient.  I thought I'd computed a cheap way of doing it, but it is wrong.  :-(

Comment: the Jacobian will be an $n^2\times n^2$ matrix in this case though

Comment: How is it computed?  I thought I'd found a cheap way of computing it as it appears that there is only a unique value per column.  The row id doesn't seem to matter...

Comment: probably best to organize it as a matrix of one forms. See my answer below.

Comment: Terrific, thank you, I will take look and digest it.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I will employ the Einstein summation convention, that is repeated indices are summed over. Now, we can write the $(i,j)$th component of $M$ as:
\begin{align}
  M^i_j=X^i_kU^k_l(X^T)^l_j
\end{align}
Now, this is a sum of real numbers, if we interpret the $X^i_k$ as coordinates on the space of $n$ by $n$ matrices (which is fine, they form a vector space, and this is a basis), then we have that by the chain rule:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial M^i_j}{\partial X^m_n}=&\frac{\partial X^i_k}{\partial X^m_n}U^k_l(X^T)^l_j+X^i_kU^k_l\frac{\partial (X^T)^l_j}{\partial X^m_n}
\end{align}
Now, we see that:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial X^i_k}{\partial X^m_n}=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if }i=m, \text{ and } n=k\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial (X^T)^l_j}{\partial X^m_n}=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if }j=m, \text{ and } n=l\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
hence:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial M^i_j}{\partial X^m_n}=&\delta^i_m\delta_k^nU^k_l(X^T)^l_j
+X^i_kU^k_l\delta^l_n\delta_j^m\\
=&\delta^i_mU^n_l(X^T)^l_j+X^i_kU^k_n\delta^m_j\\
=&\delta^i_m(U\cdot X^T)^n_j+\delta^m_j(X\cdot U)^i_n
\end{align}
Now, if we let $e_i$ be a basis for $\mathbb R^n$ and $e^i$ it's dual, we can write any linear endomorphism $A$ as the sum:
$$A=A^i_je_i\otimes e^j$$
So we see that:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial M}{\partial X^m_n}=&\frac{\partial M^i_j}{\partial X^m_n}e_i\otimes e^j\\
=&\delta^i_m(U\cdot X^T)^n_j e_i\otimes e^j+\delta^m_j(X\cdot U)^i_n e_i\otimes e^j\\
=&(U\cdot X^T)^n_je_m\otimes e^j +(X\cdot U)^i_n e_i\otimes e^m
\end{align}
i.e. $\partial M/\partial X^i_j$ is the sum of two matrices, where the first is all zeros, except in the $m$th column, and the $j$th row of the $m$th column is the $(n,j)$the component of $U\cdot X^T$, and teh second is all zeros except in the $m$th row, where the $i$th column of the $m$th row is given by the $(i,n)$th component of $X\cdot U$.

How one would want to organize in this into a Jacobian matrix is not clear to me, I would probably write it as a matrix of one forms indexed by $dX^m_n$, which is the linear functional on $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ which is identically zero on every vector that does not $e_m\otimes e^n$ component, and takes $e_m\otimes e^n$ to $1$.

Answer (score -1):

$
\newcommand\dd{\mathrm d}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\vecop{\mathop{\mathrm{vec}}}
$The total differential of $M : \R^{4,4} \to \R^{4,4}$ at $X$ is a linear map $\dd M_X : \R^{4,4} \to \R^{4,4}$. For any function $F$ we also write $\dot\dd[F(\dot X)]$ to mean $\dd F_X$. If $F(X) = G(X,X)$ for any $G$, then the following is always true:
$$
  \dot\dd[G(\dot X,\dot X)] = \dot\dd[G(\dot X,X)] + \dot\dd[G(X,\dot X)].
$$
In less transparent notation with $L(X) = G(X,Y)$ and $R(X) = G(Y,X)$ for arbitrary $Y$ independent from $X$
$$
  \dd F_X = [\dd L_X + \dd R_X]_{Y=X}.
$$
In other words, after taking the differentials we substitute $X$ for $Y$.

Finally, for any function $F$ which is linear we have
$$
  \dd F_X = F.
$$

These two rules allow us to easily compute
$$
  \dd M_X = \dot\dd[\dot XU\dot X^T] (H) = \dot\dd[\dot XUX^T] (H) + \dot\dd[XU\dot X^T] (H) = HUX^T + XUH^T
$$
the last equality following because the functions $X \mapsto XUY^T$ and $X \mapsto YUX^T$ are linear.

If we want to express this differential as some matrix, then we need to choose a way of representing $H \in \R^{4,4}$ as a vector in $\R^{16}$. Suppose we stack the columns of $H$ to get the [vectorization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) $\vecop(H)$ of $H$. This operator satisfies a useful identity with the Kronecker product $\otimes$:
$$
  \vecop(AHB) = (B^T\otimes A)\vecop(H).
$$
Then writing
$$
  \dd M_X = IHUX^T + (IHU^TX^T)^T
$$
with $I$ the $4{\times}4$ identity, we see that $\dd M_X$ can be represented by the matrix
$$
  (XU^T)\otimes I + T[(XU)\otimes I)],\quad T = \begin{pmatrix}
    J_{1,1} & J_{2,1} & J_{3,1} & J_{4,1} \\\\
    J_{1,2} & J_{2,2} & J_{3,2} & J_{4,2} \\\\
    J_{1,3} & J_{2,3} & J_{3,3} & J_{4,3} \\\\
    J_{1,4} & J_{2,4} & J_{3,4} & J_{4,4}
  \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $J_{i,j}$ is the $4{\times}4$ matrix with $1$ in the $(i,j)$ entry and $0$ everywhere else; the matrix $T$ represents the $\R^{4,4}$ transpose operation in $\R^{16}$.

Comment: Terrific - thanks!